# Using clang and gcc with a third party implementation of the standard C++ library

Tags: gcc, g++, clang, clang++, std

It's enough to just use `-nostdinc` and `-nostdinc++` if I have an implementation of the standard library that is just a third party option and should never interfere or interoperate with `libc++` and/or `libstdc++` ?

Comment: Yes. Presumably that didn't work for you; you'll have to supply more details to get a useful answer.

Comment: Not necessarily. Some parts of a `libstdc++` might use (or need to use) some compiler specific extensions or builtins. YMMV